# Classifier performance

Tags: classification

I have some data that are training data. the feature size of training data is n but feature size of my test data is m. 
which one of classifiers can do classify this data?

Comment: Hi kian, welcome to Cross validated. Please do the [tour](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour) before to ask any question. Could you add more details on your question?

Answer (score 2):

The bottom line is that you can only use the features that are common to both the training and test data sets. Example:

- Train: x1, x2, x3, x4, x5
- Test: x2, x3, x5

Then you can only train and test using x2, x3, x5. You will remove features x1 and x4 when you are training. In R x[,-c(1,4)]

Comment: Something bug me, here. Don't you need the same feature on your training  and testing dataset?

Comment: Yes, of course! Example. Train: x1, x2, x3, x4, x5. Test: x2,x3,x5. Then you can only train and test using x2, x3, x5. You will remove features x1 and x4 when you are training. In R x[,-c(1,4)]

Comment: In that case, whatever the number of feature in the training and testing data set, what count is the feature which are in both, ain't it? Basically, could you expand your answer?

Comment: Sorry, YCR, I don't understand what you mean. The bottom line is that you can only use the features that are common to both the training and test data sets, as I show in the example I gave.

Comment: So the fact that I don't understand why your answer use the number of feature, which is not a good reference to pick the features for training a model. If m < n but in the m feature, some are not in the training dataset, and the final number of feature should be described in ensemblist terms, with include or intersection, not less or more.

Comment: @stan: You've explained what you mean better in your comments than in your answer: if you edit your answer to include these points it'll be much improved.